# Angular Router duplicates my route component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, routes

I have Screen shots of the application: https://ibb.co/NmnSPNr and https://ibb.co/C0nwG4D
**info.component.ts** / **Info component where child component of Item component, this is displayed when I route to this some link.**

```
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {
  p: Post;
  paramsSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.p = {
      id: this.route.snapshot.params['id'],
      name: this.route.snapshot.params['name'],
      price: this.route.snapshot.params['price'],
      place: this.route.snapshot.params['place'],
      image: this.route.snapshot.params['image'],
      date: this.route.snapshot.params['date'],
      desc: this.route.snapshot.params['desc'],
    };
```

**item.component.ts ** / **Item component only fetches HTTP request and displayes items**

```
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  items: any;
  searchValue: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllPosts();
  }

  //GetPost's
  getAllPosts() {
    this.http.getPost().subscribe((res) => {
      this.items = res;
    });
  }
}
```

**info.component.html** / **This is the info component where I store the data from info.ts**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="imagee-div">
      <img [src]="p.image" alt="snkr1" />
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <h3>{{ p.id }}. {{ p.name }}</h3>
      <small>release date: {{ p.date }}.</small>
      <p>Price: ${{ p.price }}</p>
      <h4>More Details:</h4>
      <p>
        {{ p.desc }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**item.component.html** / **This is my Parent component, here I store the router outlet, routerLink and loop over the items**

```
<div class="row mx-auto">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="col-12 mt-3" id="main-card">
      <div class="row" id="card" *ngFor="let p of items | filter: searchValue">
        <div class="img-div">
          <img [src]="p.image" alt="" width="250px" />
        </div>
        <div class="main">
          <h4>{{ p.id }}. {{ p.name }}</h4>
          <p>Price: ${{ p.price }}</p>
          <small>{{ p.place }}</small
          ><br />
          <a
            href="#"
            [routerLink]="[
              '/item',
              p.id,
              p.name,
              p.date,
              p.desc,
              p.price,
              p.image
            ]"
          >
            <button class="btn btn-success mt-1">
              <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
            </button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `<router-outlet>`, you can use `<app-info-component>` and add *ngIf condition in the item component.

Instead of this:

```
<div class="col-8"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
```

Use this:

```
<div class="col-8">
  <app-info-component *ngIf="p.id > 0">
  </app-info-component>
</div>
```

Same in the info-component add ngIf condition has below.

```
<div *ngIf="p.id > 0" class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="imagee-div">
      <img [src]="p.image" alt="snkr1" />
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <h3>{{ p.id }}. {{ p.name }}</h3>
      <small>release date: {{ p.date }}.</small>
      <p>Price: ${{ p.price }}</p>
      <h4>More Details:</h4>
      <p>
        {{ p.desc }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried that it doesn work, and I need router-outlet there because by defaul my home.component is there. And when I chose an item the home component is gone and the details appear.

Comment: Could you share your example codebase through codesandbox.io, it will help me to work around and give you a solution.

Thanks.